# Can't Access WordPress dashboard after update

Tags: php, wordpress

I just updated a dev site I'm working on to the latest version of WordPress, immediately after doing so I can't access /wp-admin/

on /wp-admin/ I get this error on Chrome if DEBUG isn't turned on - "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Trying to access /wp-admin/admin.php I get a 404 error

If Debug is turned on in wp-config, I see the following on a blank page:

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/*****/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1569

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/*****/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1569) in /home/heavy/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216

I've tried removing all plugins, deleting HTACCESS & reverting it back to the default version, removing all customizations to functions.php, updated PHP version to 5.6 .. nothing is working.

Anyone have an idea of how I can further troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Try in a different browser. Some browsers annoyingly cache redirects. The only way to truly find the underlying cause of this is to turn everything back to vanilla WordPress. 2017 theme, no plugins activated. Then systematically turn them back on to see which is causing the error. Often these kinds of errors are caused by poorly developed code "somewhere" in the code base (either as customisations within core WordPress files, which you should never do by the way, customisations in parent theme files, which again you should never do, customisations within plugins, which again you should never do. This type of error can also be caused by trailing white spaces in various PHP files, so think about what you've just customised and undo everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but I get into similar issues. Can you try:

- keep the plugins disabled
- download a fresh new WP from wordpress.org and upload all its content **except wp-content folder** and note for difference between local files and distant files
- be sure that .htaccess fits to your needs
- open a browser that you never used on this website and go to /wp-admin

I also had this error because of WP UTF8 files containing BOM. I had to use a tool to remove it programmatically (something like this: https://github.com/GloryMind/Remove-bom-plugin-wordpress/blob/master/removed-bom.php).